# Python thread blocking during function call?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, flir, pyspin

I am using FLIR Spinnaker python interface pyspin. I noticed that saving images takes a chunk of time and I want to Parallelize it so the system could be loading a new image while the current image is saving.

My confusion is on if the python threading will help or if I will need another process(which adds its own problems). Basically the system is IO bound but via the Spinnaker library call, not a python call. Will this block the thread since it's not a system IO through the python interpreter?

Comment: Is the library support async APIs? Maybe this document can help you:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutines-and-tasks

Comment: All function calls block the thread that calls them, except ones that are specifically known to be non-blocking or asynchronous.

Comment: Thanks I added pyspin and flir to tags since they are relevant.

Comment: Have you tried it? Simplest way to know how a specific library works with your code it to just create a few threads and have one of them save the image, see if it blocks.

Comment: Why did you tag this question with multiprocessing? That and multithreading follow different sets of rules! That said, Python can execute other threads while one thread is blocked doing IO. I guess all built-in IO does that already, but for external modules that would be a "quality of implementation" issue whether they release the GIL. As others said: Try it!